# Call derived class methods from CRTP base class object

Tags: c++, crtp

Is there a way that we can call derived class's method from base class object for which base doesn't provide an interface to call? I would like to do something like this

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    using Derived = T;
    void print()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->print_();
    }

    void print_()
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }

    void a()
    {
        std::cout << "Aa" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
    void print_()
    {
        std::cout << "BD" << std::endl;
    }

    void b()
    {
        std::cout << "Bb" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C : public A<C>{
    void c()
    {
        std::cout << "Cc" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<B> b;
    A<C> c;
    b.print();
    c.print();

    B bd;
    b.a();
    bd.b(); // This works
    // b.b(); // I understand this doesn't work, but I want to make this work.


    C bc;
    c.a();
    bc.c(); // Same as class A<C> and C

}
```

I can provide interfaces to call those functions but I would like to know if this is achievable in the first place. Any solutions or comments on feasibility is much appreciated.

PS: I am just curious about this, as I got an unintentional error when I incorrectly instantiated the class.

Comment: `template<typename T> struct A : T {/*..*/};` instead? but you no longer can do `B{}.a()`.

Comment: What is the original and underlying problem (if any) you need to solve using something like this? If it's plain curiosity then that's okay, as long as you state it. But if you have an actual problem this is supposed to solve, then please ask about that problem directly instead, providing your attempt on how to solve it.

Comment: `T* A<T>::operator ->()` might be an option.

Comment: You have undefined behavior already at `b.print();` since `b` is an `A<B>` (there is no `B` i contained in `b`). When you cast to `B*` and call the non-static member function `B::print_` you call it on a non-existing object. So the question is, on what `B` instance would you expect `b.print()` and `b.b()` to operate when there is none?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It was just curiosity. Thanks for the comment, will update the question. :)

Comment: @rsvishnu "_I am just curious about this, as I got an unintentional error when I incorrectly instantiated the class._" - Then I think that what I suggested in my answer should be rather helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way that we can call derived class's method from base class object for which base doesn't provide an interface to call?

Yes, as Jarod42 suggested, you can implement `operator->` in `A`. You can't overload `operator.` so you'll have to use `->` when calling such methods.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T* operator->() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
};
```

You will now be able to compile this:

```
A<B> b;
b->print_();
b->b();
```

**But:** Your program will have undefined behavior. `b` is not a `B`. It's an `A<B>` that doesn't inherit from `B` so you will call non-`static` member functions on a non-existing object.

I suggest that you prevent instantiating `A`:s that doesn't have the proper CRTP relationship.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T* operator->() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
    
private:
    A() = default; // hidden from all ...
    friend T;      // ... except T
};
```

You can now instantiate `B`, but not `A<B>` or `C` if someone makes a bogus inheritance like this:

```
struct X {};
struct C : A<X> {}; // C can't be instantiated. A is friend of X, not C
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n1bKnMqhv)

Answer (score 1):

Simple case: If you add a static function there is a safe way (because it would not access instance date).

Complicated case: the b.b(): This *almost* works but it's definitely a bad idea. As long as function does not refer to any instance variable it would be **relatively** safe. But otherwise it will definitely crash. The reason is `b` does not have `B` **instance**.

```
      template<typename T>
  struct A
  {
     typedef typename T Derived;
     typedef typename A<T> AT;
     void print()
     {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->print_();
     }

     void print_()
     {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
     }

     void a()
     {
        std::cout << "Aa" << std::endl;
     }

     //these conversion operators are for b.b() case. very bad idea!
     operator Derived* () {
        return static_cast<T*>(this);
     }

     operator Derived& () {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
     }



  };

  struct B : public A<B>
  {
     void print_()
     {
        std::cout << "BD" << std::endl;
     }

     static void static_b()
     {
        std::cout << "Bb::static_b" << std::endl;
     }

     void b()
     {
        std::cout << "Bb::b" << std::endl;
     }

  };

  void test()
  {
     b.A<B>::Derived::static_b(); // This should work.

     b.AT::Derived::static_b(); // This works with "AT" but it's recursive template. Not good.

     ((B&)b).b(); //This works but even though operator is implicit, it cannot implicitly know what to do. Nor will "auto".

     //This works but even though operator is implicit, it cannot implicitly know what to do. Nor will "auto".
     B& br = b; 
     br.b();

  }
```